# what to mount my generator on

Tags: electrical, generator

I recently purchased a portable closed hyundai electric generator for home use, 6,3 kva, 8000se, diesel.  The generator is on wheels.  I have put it in a well ventilated storage shed more than 15 feet from my house. The shed has a concrete floor covered with tiles.  What material do you recommend that I place between the tile floor and the generator?

Comment: Why do you need to place anything under the generator? Do you mean ceramic tile on the concrete? Either of those is just fine.

Comment: -1 ... no explanation why you are asking

Comment: I am living outside of the US in Chile, South America, where there are no rules and regulations regarding electric generator use in residential areas.

Comment: This being said, the architect and constructor who remodeled the house I live in and built the shed indicated that the generator could be run in the shed with the adequate considerations.

Comment: It appears that from what everyone is indicating, this is highly not recommended.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the input from everyone and will not be running my generator in the shed.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear from the get go.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an anti-fatigue floor mat. The wheels will make divots into the squishy floor mat material and help it from moving around from the vibrations.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve?  I'm assuming that you are not proposing to run the generator while it is in an enclosed building.

Comment: @PaulLogan OP described the nature of the building and it is not a closed building.

Answer (score 0):

You should be moving the generator outside to run it.  It's in a well ventilated area in the mean time because of fuel fumes and such.  Unless your floor is easily damaged (and it shouldn't be, it's in a shed), just park it directly on the floor.  When running it, look for a level-ish spot.  Concrete is great, but dirt or stone works fine, too...

Comment: Right, think of it this way. Around your generator you have three types of air. Supply air for the intake manifold, cooling air for around your generator at recommended CFM,  and exhaust or combusted air. And all three must remain separate from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put anything under a portable generator. You're going to have to wheel it outside to legally run it anyway. What problem are you trying to solve? Oil drips? Maybe try a piece of cardboard and swap it out from time to time, as you take the generator in and out for its periodic exercise.